# Is there anyway to force all style to "block" or "none" without going through a loop?

Tags: javascript, css

ok, see this code

```
<p>This is question 1.</p>

<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42"  onclick="toggleAnswer(1)">

<p id="1">This answer1.</p>

<p>This is question 2.</p>

<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42"  onclick="toggleAnswer(2)">

<p id="2">This answer2.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleAnswer(no){
        if (document.getElementById(no).style.display=="none")
        {
          document.getElementById(no).style.display="block";
        }
        else
        {
          document.getElementById(no).style.display="none";
        }
 }    

   </script>
```

The code means that there are many questions and if we click on the image next to a specific question the answer will appear accordingly.

Now, I want to make a button "**show All**" & "**close ALL**". WHen people click "**show All**" it will show all answers and when clicking  "**close ALL**", it will close all answers.

My question is that

**Is there anyway to force all elements inside a page to have style of either "block" or "none" without going through a loop?**

Comment: Use css and only show what is needed by toggling a class that over rides the default

Comment: You will still need to loop to assign the CSS class

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using a loop here.

Comment: @Tom - For what purpose would you like to avoid the use of a loop?

Comment: Why not just add a class to the questions and use getElementsByClassName()? Anyway I would use jQuery or Zepto js if you're planning to do it this way since getElementsByClassName() is not supported in all browsers(IE going at it again...).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS class on a parent element:
https://jsfiddle.net/ckyoxobp/

HTML

```
<div id="questions">
    <button id="toggle">Show all answers</button>
    <p>This is question 1.</p>
    <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42">
    <p id="1" class="answer">This answer1.</p>
    <p>This is question 2.</p>
    <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42">
    <p id="2" class="answer">This answer2.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var questions = document.getElementById('questions');
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

function toggleAll() {
  if (questions.classList.contains('show-all')) {
    questions.classList.remove('show-all');
    toggle.innerText = 'Show all answers';
  } else {
    questions.classList.add('show-all');
    toggle.innerText = 'Hide all answers';
  }
}

toggle.onclick = toggleAll;
```

CSS

```
#questions .answer {
  display: none;
}

#questions.show-all .answer {
  display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I should have been more explicit about browser compatibility; I simply wanted to show an example of using a class on a parent element. [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) isn't supported in some versions of some browsers, notably IE9 and earlier, and IE10 has limit limited support of it. However, [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) has near-complete coverage.

Modifying an element's classes is beyond the scope of this question, but [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/2287529) will give you a good start.

Comment: why it didn't work on my Page? are you sure it can work on all browsers?

Comment: seem it doesn't understand classList